# mpmath and precision issue

Tags: python, mpmath

### The precision of mpmath.sqrt(2) is not what I expected. What am I doing wrong?

```
import mpmath as mp

mp.prec = 20

mp.nprint(mp.sqrt(2), 20)
```

result:  `1.4142135623730951455`

expected: `1.4142135623730950488` (according to [this reference](https://nerdparadise.com/math/reference/2sqrt10000))

Answer (score 1):

`mp.prec` is the binary precision.  `mp.dps` is the decimal one.

```
In [588]: mpmath.mp.dps=20                                                                       
In [589]: mpmath.sqrt(2)                                                                         
Out[589]: mpf('1.4142135623730950488011')
```

With this setting:

```
In [590]: print(mpmath.mp)                                                                       
Mpmath settings:
  mp.prec = 70                [default: 53]
  mp.dps = 20                 [default: 15]
  mp.trap_complex = False     [default: False]
```

cf with the default

```
Mpmath settings:
  mp.prec = 53                [default: 53]
  mp.dps = 15                 [default: 15]
  mp.trap_complex = False     [default: False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting case. Using pythons `Decimal` it gives the same result as the reference you listed, but using `float` or `math.sqrt()` seems to give a different result.

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> '{:.25f}'.format(2**0.5)                            # Result 1
'1.4142135623730951454746219'
>>> '{:.25f}'.format(math.sqrt(2))                      # Result 1
'1.4142135623730951454746219'
>>> '{:.25f}'.format(math.sqrt(Decimal('2')))           # Result 1
'1.4142135623730951454746219'
>>> '{:.25f}'.format(Decimal('2') ** Decimal('0.5'))    # Result 2
'1.4142135623730950488016887'

# The reference you listed                              # Result 2
'1.4142135623730950488016887'
```

Your library is probably using `float` internally.

But I think this is normal and NOT a bug, since `float`s are not meant to be 100% precise; they are meant to be fast on the machine.

Comment: But mpmath was implemented for specifically managing arbitrary precision floating point, and I thought it should return the accurate representation of the digits(accuracy over speed)... 

Tnx for the reply :-)